# c# iteration with no answer first 2 times. Output on third try over and over again

Tags: c#, object, while-loop

I wrote this as a simple dice game. It works as I want except it iterates 3 times with no answer on the first two iterations. The third time the question is asked and answered a output shows up.

No idea where in my code is the issue, I have gone over it over and over....lol any help =)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


/* I am very confused but for soem reason it only returns a value every 3 tries....I dont understand
 * I looked through the program and the only thing that occurs 3 times is the if else if else if statement 
 * but I dont see how that would do it....
 */
namespace Lab11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {//declared constants
            const int NUM_1 = 1;
            const int NUM_6 = 6;

            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tWelcome To a Game of Dice!");
            //Do while statement repeating the "roll again" question and performing the random numbers
            do
            {
                Again();

                Random ran = new Random();

                //if else if else if statement doing the random numbers and telling you rolled snake or box
                if (Again() == true)
                {
                    int num1 = ran.Next(1, 7);
                    int num2 = ran.Next(1, 7);
                    //if else statement determining the output for each roll in the console.
                    if (num1 == NUM_6 && num2 == NUM_6)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nYou Rolled BoxCars");
                    }
                    else if (num1 == NUM_1 && num2 == NUM_1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nYou rolled Snake-Eyes");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nYou Rolled...{0} and {1}", num1, num2);
                    }
                }
            } while (Again() == true);
            //Goodbye if you press 'n'
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nGoodBye");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        //the yes or no method asking if you want to play again
        //this is where I think the issue is but I dont see where or how....
        static bool Again()
        {
            char response;

            Console.Write("\n\nWould you like to roll the dice (y or n)? ");
            response = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            response = char.ToLower(response);

            if (response == 'y')
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }          

    }
}
```

Comment: You've got the correct answer. However, the question wouldn't have ever risen had you used a debugger. You should learn how to use one.

Comment: Um if you read this, what is a debugger. Id love to find out more just new to c# and programming in general. I am googling it but any veteran direction would be great if you have the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Again();

Random ran = new Random();

if (Again() == true)
{
    // ...
```

Here, you are calling `Again()` twice, which causes it to prompt the user twice. You could change it like this:

```
bool rollAgain = Again();

Random ran = new Random();

if (rollAgain == true)
{
    // ...
```

You have a similar issue here:

```
} while (Again() == true);
```

To solve everything, you could probably introduce the `rollAgain` variable outside the `do-while` statement and assign it inside.

Comment: Purely semantics, but `if (Again() == true)` is not required, it can be simply `if (Again())`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Again` way too many times. Do something like this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tWelcome To a Game of Dice!");            
while (Again()) {
   Random ran = new Random();
   int num1 = ran.Next(1, 7);
   int num2 = ran.Next(1, 7);
   if (num1 == NUM_6 && num2 == NUM_6) { ... 
   else .. // the rest of your checking code here
}
```

So now you are only calling `Again` once per loop. If you step through the code (including stepping into `Again`), you should be able to see what's happening.

Comment: I see exactly what you mean, thanks a lot. I see how I was calling it over and over and did not think anything of it. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop here, and call `Again` one time

```
while (Again())
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    int num1 = ran.Next(1, 7);
    int num2 = ran.Next(1, 7);
    //if else statement determining the output for each roll in the console.
    if (num1 == NUM_6 && num2 == NUM_6)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou Rolled BoxCars");
    }
    else if (num1 == NUM_1 && num2 == NUM_1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou rolled Snake-Eyes");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou Rolled...{0} and {1}", num1, num2);
    }
}
```